# How to add hypertext link to Cluster Force Layout circle

Tags: d3.js

I have a cluster force layout which works fine, and I can add text to the circles. However, when I try to add a hypertext link, nothing is displayed. 
What is the problem with my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/o3zbKpgHVCTwpiBQVNjF?p=preview)?

The code for the text is

```
node.append("a")
    .text(function(d){
        return d.name;
    })
    .attr("href", function(d){
         return '/profile/'+d.name;
    })
    .attr("dx", -10)
    .text(function(d){
         return d.name;
    })
    .style("stroke", "white");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVGs you are not allowed to put textual content into the `<a>` itself. For an overview of what is actually allowed in an `<a>` element have a look at the [*Content model*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#Links) section of the spec.

You need to wrap another `text` element around your link labels:

```
node.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
         return '/profile/'+d.name;
    })
    .append("text")                   // <-- Wrap <text> element around link label
    .text(function(d){
        return d.name;
    })
    .attr("dx", -10)
    .style("stroke", "white");
```